# Embedding PDF changes zoom value of following web pages in Vivaldi

Tags: pdf, zooming, embed, vivaldi

I want to embed a PDF file in a web page with a predefined page fit property. Problem is: When the resulting zoom value is != 100% all web pages of the same site visited afterwards will be zoomed to the zoom value of the previously displayed PDF file, at least in Vivaldi; Chromium and Firefox seem to act as expected. Is there a way to make Vivaldi change the zoom level only for the PDF and not for all following pages? The code I used is this:

```
<object data='mydocument.pdf#view=FitV&zoom=page-height' type='application/pdf' width='880' height='1000'></object>
```

Using the `<embed>` or `<iframe>` elements instead doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Not quite so. Chrome listens only to `view` and Firefox only to `zoom`.

Comment: Even dropping `zoom` (and with this also the support for Firefox) completely doesn't help. Seems like Chrome simply translates `view` to `zoom`. I also tried the `iframe` method, but apparently Chrome stores the zoom factor of the last loaded object and applies this value to all following pages... :-(

Comment: I tried to add another PDF with `#zoom=100` to override the previous zoom value, but Chrome applies the first value even to the new PDF, regardless of using `object`, `embed` or `iframe`.

Comment: Alright, I have to confess I found this issue in Vivaldi not Chrome but assumed this was related to the browser engine shared by all Blink-based browsers like Chrome and alike. But now I checked in Chromium and the issue is gone. So it seems to be a bug in Vivaldi alone. Will file a bug report there. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Unfortunately, Vivaldi has no public bug tracker.

Comment: I know, but I mean it's just not public for others to follow the issue...